# How to set a reminder?

Tags: android

I have tried many solutions from stackoverflow but none of them worked...I want to set the repeating alarm to get notified for pending bills...

so far i have tried this,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pending_sales_purchase);
    manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,5);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2018);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,8);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,35);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent );
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

> MyBroadcastReceiver class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked1111.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "dddd";
        String description = "aaaa";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("a", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

     intent = new Intent(context, PendingSalesPurchaseActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "a")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_search_commit)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `<receiver>` element in the manifest for `MyBroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: Do you want to repeat alarm on some time interval or monthly?

Comment: like once due date passes it should show notification everyday till it is fulfilled

Comment: Just noticed that you aren't actually issuing the `Notification` in the Receiver. You need to call a `NotificationManager#notify()` method there, with the `Notification` you've built.

Comment: now what i want is it should get fired everyday on same time

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to set notification.

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

For repeating alarm everyday, You need to use [setRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

```
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent );
```

Of, if you don't require repeating alarm on exact time then it's better to use [setInexactRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

```
 alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent );
```

> Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements;
>   for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at
>   the top of every hour. These alarms are more power-efficient than the
>   strict recurrences traditionally supplied by `setRepeating(int, long,
>   long, PendingIntent)`, since the system can adjust alarms' delivery
>   times to cause them to fire simultaneously, avoiding waking the device
>   from sleep more than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use this code for daily notification on same time.**

```
  public static void setReminder(Context context, int hour, int min)
    {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar setcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if(setcalendar.before(calendar))
            setcalendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);

        // Enable a receiver

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, cls);//Class Name from where it trigger
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, cls);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, DAILY_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setcalendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    }
```